# checking if a site collection is readonly using powershell csom

Tags: 2013, powershell, csom

i have a list of sites that should be readonly but i am trying to loop through the list and determine if they are or not, however it doesnt seem to me that the readonly property of the site collection is returned.  Im not sure if im doing something wrong though

```
BlockedSites | ForEach-Object{
    $contextTemp = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($_["RamLockSiteUrl"])
    $SiteTemp = $contextTemp.Site
    $contextTemp.Load($SiteTemp)
    $context.executeQuery()

    #check if the site is locked
    #if not put into error collection to send to admins to check via email
    if($SiteTemp.ReadOnly -eq $true){
        #if($NetworkSitesInLockedListButNotLocked -eq $null){$NetworkSitesInLockedListButNotLocked = @()}
        #$NetworkSitesInLockedListButNotLocked += $_["RamLockSiteUrl"]
        Write-Host "read only"
    }else{
        Write-Host "not read only"
    }
}
```

Comment: on prem or o365? check this

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE check what?  Is there supposed to be a link there?

Answer (score -1):

**How to Check Site Lock Status using POWERSHELL?**

1. You can Navigate to: **Central Administration > Application Management > Configure Quotas and Locks** to get lock status.
2. Get Lock status with STSADM
3. `stsadm -o getsitelock -URL http://sharepoint.crescent.com`
4. Retrieve Site lock status

Using PowerShell:

```
Get-SPSite "http://sharepoint.crescent.com" | Select ReadOnly,Readlocked,WriteLocked
```

**If you want to retrieve lock status for all site collections.**

***Use below PowerShell:***

```
Add-pssnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ErrorAction silentlycontinue

#Get All Site Collections of a web app
$Sites = Get-SPWebApplication "http://sharepoint.crescent.com" | Get-SPSite -limit all | foreach {

#Check Lock Status

#No Locks Applied?
if ($_.ReadOnly -eq $false -and $_.ReadLocked -eq $false -and $_.WriteLocked -eq $false) 
{
$Result ="Unlocked"
}
#Read-only Lock?
elseif ($_.ReadOnly -eq $true -and $_.ReadLocked -eq $false -and $_.WriteLocked -eq $true) 
{
$Result = "Read-Only"
}
#Adding Content Prevented?
elseif ($_.WriteLocked -eq $true -and $_.ReadLocked -eq $false -and $_.ReadOnly -eq $false) 
{
$Result = "Adding Content Prevented"
}
#No Access?
elseif ($_.ReadOnly -eq $null -and $_.ReadLocked -eq $null -and $_.WriteLocked -eq $null) 
{
$Result="No Access"
}

#Write the Result to CSV file separeted with Tab character
$_.RootWeb.Title +"`t" + $_.URL + "`t" + $Result | Out-File LockStatus.txt -Append

}
```

**How to Check Site Lock Status using CSOM?**

```
# replace these details (also consider using Get-Credential to enter password securely as script runs).. 
$username = "SomeUser@SomeOrg.onmicrosoft.com" 
$password = "SomePassword" 
$url = "https://SomeSite.sharepoint.com"

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force 

# the path here may need to change if you used e.g. C:\Lib.. 
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 
# note that you might need some other references (depending on what your script does) for example:
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll" 

# connect/authenticate to SharePoint Online and get ClientContext object.. 
$clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url) 
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $securePassword) 
$clientContext.Credentials = $credentials 

if (!$clientContext.ServerObjectIsNull.Value) 
{ 
    Write-Host "Connected to SharePoint Online site: '$Url'" -ForegroundColor Green 
} 

$rootWeb = $clientContext.Web
$childWebs = $rootWeb.Webs
$clientContext.Load($rootWeb)
$clientContext.Load($childWebs)
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

function processWeb($web)
{
    $clientContext.Load($web)
    $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
    Write-Host "Web URL is" $web.Url
    Write-Host "$web.readonly"
}

foreach ($childWeb in $childWebs)
{
    processWeb($childWeb)
}
```

Comment: This is not CSOM.  I need to use CSOM so it can run as a scheduled task from a remote server.

Comment: You had mentioned Power Shell CSOM in your question so i provide you Power Shell code. Please ask a question with proper details first. thanks

Comment: Have you tried the code mentioned in my updated answer? You asked for Powershell CSOM.